# What does "of the other" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In *Pulp Fiction (1994)*, Captain Koons says to Kid:

> Captain Koons: See, I was a good friend of your dad's. We were in that
> Hanoi pit of hell together...over five years. Hopefully...you'll never
> have to experience this yourself, but when two men are in a situation
> like me and  your dad were...for as long as we were, you take on
> certain responsibilities **of the other**. If it'd been me who'd--not made
> it, Major Coolidge'd be talking right now to my son Jim. But the way
> it turned out, I'm talking to you.

What does "of the other" mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Captain Koons is talking about two men in general, lets say man A and man B.
By saying one takes over the responsibilities of the other, he means that, for example man A takes over the responibilities of man B, or the other way round.